# Django model to field

Tags: django, django-models

want to use a model to another models field  in django. Is the following possible?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    students_name = #class foo fields
    fathers_name = #class foo fields
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a  foreign key relationship by using [`models.ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) if you want to choose records from another model:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    students_name = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    fathers_name = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

This will let you choose from saved records of the model `Foo` when storing a new object of `Bar`.

**Edit**:

For (over)clarification on the relationship this creates, this will link two separate entities of the object `Foo` to `Bar`.

[image: Relationship Diagram]

The two instances of `Foo` doesn't have to be the same object, but can be different objects of the model `Foo`.

Comment: Understood. But want to create a modelform to show students_name and fathers_name field seperately. Another example: guess someone has primary address and secondary address. Both fields are same. How to use that

Comment: The example above will let you choose separate records from the model Foo, both for `students_name` and for `fathers_name`. The model `Bar` will then have linked two separate instances of the model `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    students_name = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fathers_name = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

If you need some different type of relation refer these.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/

Comment: Understood. But want to create a modelform to show students_name and fathers_name field seperately. Another example: guess someone has primary address and secondary address. Both fields are same. How to use that

Comment: updated my answer, FYI: me and @Johan are saying same thing. This should work